# How can I interpret a year-naive, RFC 3339 datetime string in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, rfc3339

I am interfacing with an API which gives year-naive RFC 3339 datetime strings for representing a users birthday. Naturally, I want to interpret this as some sort of `datetime` object - However, the python `datetime` library doesn't support datetime strings with values less than one.

Here's an example datetime string given by the API: `0000-09-01T00:00:00-00:00` (Notice the year is set to `0000`). If I were to just throw this into `datetime.fromisoformat`, it unsuprisingly raises an error:

```py
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: datetime.fromisoformat("0000-09-01T00:00:00-00:00")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e1d8a5624d92> in <module>
----> 1 datetime.fromisoformat("0000-09-01T00:00:00-00:00")

ValueError: year 0 is out of range
```

If I were to entirely remove the year section of the string, It gives the following:

```py
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: datetime.fromisoformat("09-01T00:00:00-00:00")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a027335f00c1> in <module>
----> 1 datetime.fromisoformat("09-01T00:00:00-00:00")

ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '09-01T00:00:00-00:00'
```

At first, I thought this was a bug or limitation. But after a little research, I found that the [RFC3339 Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-1) states the following in its introduction:

> All dates and times are assumed to be in the "current era", somewhere between 0000AD and 9999AD.

Assuming that this range is inclusive (This is based on the other uses of the term "between" within the standard, although it is never strictly specified), it is implied that the datetime module does not conform to the RFC3339 standard as it hard codes a minimum and maximum year value and also makes it a required value. However, it never claims that it does conform to the standard. So the new issue is that if the included library doesn't support RFC3339, what does?

**My question is:** Is there a method of interpreting this string as some kind of datetime object or use a third-party library?

Comment: There is no year 0. The year 1 AD followed the year 1 BC.

Comment: Yep, I know. However, I have no control over the data I'm given by the API.

Comment: The documentation you linked to is for the API, not the Python `datetime` library.

Comment: Python's datetime class won't handle year 0, see [datetime.min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.min). Python datetime docs also don't claim `fromisoformat` will parse arbitrary ISO 8601 formats, see [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)

Comment: If you're trying to represent the person's yearly birthday, the year is irrelevant (unless they're born on Feb 29). Remove the year and parse it without it, then get the month and day from that.

Comment: @Barmar removing the year will also raise an exception. Stating that the format of the string is invalid.

Comment: why not replace the year with a "missing value identifier", e.g. `replace('0000', '2996')`? hoping this code won't be still in use in a few hundred years...

Comment: Don't use `fromisoformat()`, use `datetime.strptime()`.

Comment: @Barmar `strptime` won't help, see datetime.min.

Comment: @MrFuppes  That is what I was considering. However it could lead to unintended side effects if someone were to try and interact with the year attribute. I'd rather it explicity raised an exception if I were to put in dummy data for the year. Its looking more likely that I will have to create my own implementation of `datetime`.

Comment: if you want it to raise an exception, why not capture `year 0 out of range` and re-raise it with a meaningful error message? would not require re-writing datetime ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes Use `strptime()` with a format string that has a literal `0000-` rather than `%Y-` Or remove the `0000-` and then use `strptime()` without a year specification.

Comment: @Barmar sure, but that would require capturing the exception first, so that "normal" years would still be parsed

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought it was always returning year 0.

Comment: Anyway, the statement "API is not in compliance with RFC 3339" is wrong. The API is in compliance, `datetime.fromisoformat()` isn't. But it doesn't claim to be.

Comment: side note, there is [astropy.time](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/time/index.html#id3) which supports year 0 but doesn't parse RFC3339 (the UTC offset removed, it works with `format='isot'`).

Comment: @Barmar I'm basing the claim of "not in compliance" on the assumption made in the standard that all datetimes are "within the current era" i.e: 0<year<9999.

Comment: I think it means `0 <= year <= 9999`

Comment: @Barmar I think you're right actually. If you take a look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.7. It uses "between" inclusively. In which case, it *does* conform to standard. The new question is how can I parse an RFC3339 datetime string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no [year 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero) in the [Anno Domini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini) date presentation system.

A quick look at the common datetime alternatives ([Pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io), [Arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)) show that the `ValueError` error for parsing an ISO format string with `0000-` as the year is universal. That is not a valid year and the error lies with the data source.

A date with only a month and a day is not really a date - it is ambiguous. Is the date `2/23` before or after `3/1`? Is `2/23` + 6 days the end of February or the first of March? In both cases, it depends entirely on the year.

It appears that the [Square API](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/objects/Customer#definition__property-birthday) is using `0000-` as a flag for the year being optional since some people do not want to disclose their age.

If your data is standardized to year `0000`, you can probably just do a string replacement to standardize on year 1:

```
from datetime import datetime

s="0000-09-01T00:00:00-00:00"

>>> datetime.fromisoformat(s.replace("0000-","0001-"))
datetime.datetime(1, 9, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Or, as stated in comments, perhaps use `0004` to accommodate 2/29 as a birthday:

```
s="0000-02-29T00:00:00-00:00"

>>> datetime.fromisoformat(s.replace("0000-","0004-"))
datetime.datetime(4, 2, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

This is a partial solution at best. Again, a date without a year is not a date and you will need to write and validate a lot of code to try and solve the ambiguity for sorting, comparisons, date offsets, presentation, etc.

Comment: `0004` would be better in case it's a leap day.

Comment: This is what I first chose to do as a way of avoiding the problem. However it has two of its own problems. The first is that a user could inadvertantly assume that the year was valid and not just dummy data. The other is that If I want to do it the other way (Send a year-naive datetime TO the API) I would need to catch all datetime objects and ensure it is serialised back into a string correctly. This is technically possible, but is quite hacky and doesn't solve the first of the two issues.

Comment: A month and day without a year is not really a valid date. By definition, you will need to do something 'hacky' to use a datetime object or you will need to have your own date type object. Perhaps focus on the to/from API component to ensure all the required to/from transformations are done consistently. You can also have consistent presentation code so the date is presented as only a `M/D` birthday so the user never sees a year.

Comment: Considering the options, I think this is the only suitable solution other than creating my own implementation or asking the developers to change their API. As such, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Nit-pick: Why is year 0 invalid, just because the Python implementation starts at year 1? Other languages have no issues with it afaik.

Comment: @MrFuppes: Year 0 is not a valid value for 'common usage' or AD / BC dates. (The year 0 IS valid for astronomical and ISO 8601 presentation schemes.) So then it becomes a series of questions: What calendar am I using? How many years are in the range 1BC to 1AD, 2 or 3? And how do I handle invalid dates, silently or with an error? Perl and Ruby do handle year 0 differently than Python. (But then there are 3 years in the range -0001 to 0001. Python does not handle negative years in `datetime`.) I am not aware of how other languages treat this.

Comment: Given what you describe, from a practical point of view, year zero seems like a good no-value flag to me. so I'd consider this a limitation (of Python). On the other hand, `datetime` actually doesn't seem a very good match for what is asked / what I think the OP wants to do. Creating a simple "birthday" class might be a good alternative to using `datetime` in the first place.

Comment: @MrFuppes: year 0 IS a good flag, agreed. I do not agree that it is a Python limitation. The `datetime` class was designed for complete dates -- not ambiguous ones. A 'birthday' class is the solution of course (which might even be a subclass of `datetime`) but there would be a fair amount of work to do to support `datetime` like functionality. How do you sort a date without a year? How do you add days with a variable number of days in an unknown year?